# Format List View in JSON - row borders? My own styles?

Tags: json, sharepoint, view

I have a list view in SharePoint Online that I'm formatting using JSON. I'm trying to set it so the rows have top borders (ideally, I'd like it to be conditional, but let's walk before we run).

I don't want to do anything else. There are a lot of columns, so I don't want to create a child for each field if I can avoid it. Besides, I don't think that will do what I want.

I've done lots of looking around (including the examples in GitHub, UI Fabric) and it appears that the only way to format a row in a view is to apply a class, and the only classes I can find that seem to be available are the built in ones like sp-field-severity--good. I couldn't find any that just had a top border.

So my questions are these:
- is there a comprehensive list of these classes somewhere? 
- can I set a CSS style on a row or create my own CSS class to apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint provide some class for set border color.

Example.

```
{
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "ms-borderColor-themeDark"
}
```

We can open the IE F12 developer tools, switch the Debugger tab, search "ms-border", we can see only some class about the border color.

[image]

For custom the list view, we can also create custom style for the grid and using SPFx extension to injects custom CSS to achieve some requirement.

**Solution**: [react-application-injectcss](https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss)

**Article**: [Inject Custom CSS on SharePoint Modern Pages using SPFx Extensions](https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/05/08/inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-extensions/)

Comment: Unfortunately, the ms-borderColor-themeLight class didn't appear when I put it in the JSON.

Comment: I think maybe the sp-field-customFormatBackground class might do some of what I want (though it doesn't look like borders are an option), but I can't find anything about how to use it for a view, just a column. (https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3089)

Comment: To format a row, I suggest you set the background color to instead of set border.